# How to load a JavaScript file in the Blazor client index.html

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have the following JavaScript code in a .js file:

```
export function testAlert() {
  alert('Testing Blazor');
}
```

When I added this to my *Razor component*, I get a warning:

[image]

I added the following to the *index.html* file - as recommended:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <title>BlazorTest</title>
  <base href="/" />
  <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="BlazorTest.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/testing.js"></script>
</head>
```

Modified the component accordingly:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
  await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("testAlert");
}
```

When I load the page, I get the following error:

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'testAlert' ('testAlert' was undefined).

I checked the source of the page, and it looked like this:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <title>BlazorTest</title>
  <base href="/" />
  <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="BlazorTest.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

What happened to the **modified** *index.html* with the loaded script?

Comment: Sometimes the index.html file is cached by the browser. That may be the case here. Have you tried reloading the page after clearing the cache? Ctrl-F5 usually does it for me.

Comment: I think if you remove the export from the function, and make sure you have saved the changes to index.html  your code should work.

Comment: Using "export" from JS or TS "compiles" to some funky code that even re-instantiates objects. I personally dislike it very much. Anyway, perhaps removing "export" will fix this, otherwise - see what you actually get in the browser devtools, maybe there is a layer of objects that you actually get and you may need to match those namespaces in the JS Interop call

Comment: @EricKing Yes, it looks like it was heavily cached: I added some HTML code and the change was invisible until I hit Ctrl+F5. Strangely the next edit didn't require it, and immediately refreshed. Promote your comment to an answer, I'll accept is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the index.html file is cached by the browser. That may be the case here.

Usually forcing a refresh with Ctrl-F5 will force a download of the newly edited file.